# How to convert given string in comma seperated characters in java?

Tags: java

```java
public class StringDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name = "String";
        char[] c = name.toCharArray();
        for (char ch : c) {
            System.out.print(ch);
                System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me output as

```
S,t,r,i,n,g,
```

I don't want that last comma, how to get output as S,t,r,i,n,g

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it on a higher level without writing your own loop. It's not faster or anything, but the code is more clear about what it's doing: *"Split my string into characters and join it back together, separated by commas!"* ...

```
String name = "String";
String separated = String.join(",", name.split(""));
System.out.println(separated);
```

EDIT: `String.join()` is available from Java 1.8 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for this task.

What you need, is to apply some logic that can distinguish whether or not a comma is needed. You loop through the characters just like you did and you always append a comma **before** the next character, except on the first iteration.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "String";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : test.toCharArray()) {
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
S,t,r,i,n,g
```

Another way without `StringBuilder` and using just a traditional for loop, but using the same logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "String";
    char[] chars = test.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        System.out.print(chars[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
S,t,r,i,n,g
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but for this you need a `for` loop based on the length of c, other solutions are not as straight IMHO:

```
String name="String";
char[] c = name.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    char ch = c[i];
    System.out.print(ch);
    if( i != c.length -1 ){
        System.out.print(",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additional 2 Cents:

You can stream the character `int` values, map them to a `List<String>` where each element is a single `char` as `String` and finally use `String.join(..., ...)` in order to get the desired result, a comma separated `String` of all the characters in the original `String`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // take an example String
    String name = "Stringchars";
    // make a list of characters as String of it by streaming the chars
    List<String> nameCharsAsString = name.chars()
                                        // mapping each one to a String
                                        .mapToObj(e -> String.valueOf((char) e))
                                        // and collect them in a list
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // then join the elements of that list to a comma separated String
    String nameCharsCommaSeparated = String.join(",", nameCharsAsString);
    // and print it
    System.out.println(nameCharsCommaSeparated);
}
```

Running this code results in the following output:

```
S,t,r,i,n,g,c,h,a,r,s
```

This is just another possibility of getting your desired result, it is not necessarily the best solution.

Comment: I feel like this is quite an overhead for just splitting the string. Not only that it's creating a an intermediate collection, but also the code could be much more readable by just doing `name.split("");` (which returns a string array you can pass to `String.join()` in the same way).

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I actually upvoted the answer that uses `String.join()` and `name.split()` because it's just simpler. I will leave this answer and comment for future readers not expecting any upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream` to do that. Please check below,

```
String result = Arrays.stream(name.split("")).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Output:

```
S,t,r,i,n,g
```